# Calculate a average time between two time flutter dart

Tags: flutter, dart, average, timepicker

i am using timepickersipnner i want to calculate average between two time..
for example if my start time is 9:00 and end time is 11:00 average should be 10:00..
accutally my time is in 24hoursformat ..

my time picker code

```
DateTime _dateTimeStart = DateTime.now();  
startTime.text = (_dateTimeStart.hour.toString().padLeft(2, '0') + ':') +
      _dateTimeStart.minute.toString().padLeft(2, '0');

 
  
TimePickerSpinner(
             is24HourMode: false,
             normalTextStyle: TextStyle(
                 fontSize: 24,
                 color: Color(0xff000000).withOpacity(.25)
             ),
             highlightedTextStyle: TextStyle(
                 fontSize: 24,
                 color: Color(0xff000000)
             ),
             spacing: 20,
             minutesInterval: 30,
             isForce2Digits: true,
             onTimeChange: (time) {
               setState(() {
                 print(time);
                 _dateTimeStart = time;
                 print(_dateTimeStart);

               });
             },
           ),` child:ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  startTime.text = (_dateTimeStart.hour.toString().padLeft(2, '0') + ':') +
                      _dateTimeStart.minute.toString().padLeft(2, '0');
              //    _from = DateTime(_dateTimeStart.hour , _dateTimeStart.minute);
                  Navigator. pop(context, false);
                });
              },
              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                ),
                primary: Color(0xff495F5E),
                minimumSize: Size(250, 50),
              ),
              child: Text('OK',style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xffFFFFFF),fontSize: 16,fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),),

          )
```

Comment: Can you include more about `TimePickerSpinner` or it is just ok to have avg dateTime

Comment: i want to calculate avg time ..i have two textfield in which i am choosing time( from -to).. i am using this timepicker spinner ..

Answer (score 0):

You can get the difference between time and then add half duration on startDateTime. You can use `TimeOfDay.fromDateTime` for converting.

```dart
  DateTime? startTime, endTime;

  TimeOfDay? avgTime() {
    if (startTime != null && endTime != null) {
      final difference = endTime!.difference(startTime!).inMinutes;

      final result = startTime!.add(Duration(minutes: difference ~/ 2));
      return TimeOfDay.fromDateTime(result);
    }
  }
```

If you like to check end time is before startTime, include another condition like `endTime!.isAfter(startTime!)`.

You can get the average time like

```dart
 Text("avg Time ${avgTime()?.hour}:${avgTime()?.minute} "),
```

Find more about [`DateTime`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/DateTime-class.html)

Comment: hii.. i want to round off my datetime minutes .. for eg if it is 6:35 it should 6:30 ,,or if it is 6:45 and it is 6:50